# difference between typecasts (int**) and int(*)

Tags: c++

In the following piece of code i see that

```
int i=2;int j=3;
int* arr[]={&i,&j};

cout<<*&arr[0]<<endl; //its arr[0] i.e. &i
cout<<(int*)&arr[0]<<endl;  //address of 1st element of arr.
cout<<(int**)&arr[0]<<endl; // same as above even though now typecasted to int**
cout<<*(int**)&arr[0]<<endl; // this prints the address of arr[0] in hex
cout<<*(int*)&arr[0]<<endl; //this prints the address of arr[0] in int.
```

**Questions:**

1. What does the following mean:

   a. *Meaning* and *Difference* between `(int**)&arr[0]` and `(int*)&arr[0]`

   b. *Meaning* and *Difference* between `*(int**)&arr[0]` and `*(int*)&arr[0]`
2. Why `*(int**)&arr[0]` and `*(int*)&arr[0]` prints address in hex and int respectively?

Comment: Casting doesn't change a value; it just changes the compile-time type.

Comment: `int(*)` appears in the title, but nowhere in the question.

Comment: @Slaks: That's wrong in general (or could be phrased better, depending on what you mean). e.g. to the extent a `double` and an `int` can be considered to have the same value, `(int)3.5` is certainly not the same as `3.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers are typically printed in base 10, while pointers are printed in base 16, which explains the difference in outputs you're observing:

*First off:*

`(int**)&arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer

`(int*)&arr[0]` is a pointer to an integer

Both of these are pointers, so they are printed as hexadecimals.

*Then:*

`*(int**)&arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer, dereferenced once. In other words, it's a pointer.

`*(int*)&arr[0]` is a pointer to an integer, dereferenced once. In other words, it's an integer.

*Finally:*

`*&arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer, dereferenced once. In other words, it's a pointer to an integer.

The fact that the array is an array of pointers is only relevant to this case, because in each of the prior cases the first thing you do is cast the value of `&arr[0]`.

Comment: You're welcome! If you like the answer, please accept it so future visitors know it solved your problem.

Comment: I'd like to point out that &arr[ 0 ] is of type (int * * ). This means any cast of &arr[0] that is not (int * * ) produces an invalid result, because the "pointer to an array of pointers" can't really be reinterpreted to anything else reasonably. The cast (int * )&arr[0] gives you the address of an int * *, but the result can't be used that way. That is, *(int * )&arr[0] does not return a valid integer value, but * *(int * * )&arr[0] does (that's the value of i)

Comment: @Alex: these 5 examples are all c style casts right? What would the syntax be for these 5 examples if i were to do c++ style type cast?

Comment: A C-style case of `(int)*&arr[0]` corresponds to `static_cast<int*>(&arr[0])`